# creating a cookie in CANJS

Tags: canjs

I am creating a  application using CANJS. To display the user Information basing on the cookie I am not not knowing how to create and delete a cookie using CANJS.

can some one please help me

Answer (score 1):

Go to http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html and [type cookie in the search box](http://javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#!jQuery.cookie).

```
$.cookie('name','value');

var value = $.cookie('name');
```

Or you could use http://jquerypp.com/

Answer (score 1):

may be I'm late but you can try [jquery++ cookies](http://jquerypp.com/#cookie)